# Check Database value,when there is no interaction of user with session

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, invalidation

I have written a test.jsp,web.xml and Session listener.For session timeout i am using `HttpSessionListener` feature.My session is getting invalidated after 1 minute,when there is no user interaction with the session.
Technology used : JSP,Servlet
JSP

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Servlet Session Listener example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add User Screen</h2>

        <span style="float: right"> 
            <a href="DestroySession.jsp">Destroy this session</a>
             </span>

        <form method="post" action="AddUser.jsp">
            <h3>Enter Username to Add in List</h3>
            <input type="text" name="user"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add User"/>
        </form>

    <%
        List<String> users = (List<String>)session.getAttribute("users");
        for(int i=0; null!=users && i < users.size(); i++) {
            out.println("<br/>" + users.get(i));
        }
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java code

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private int sessionCount = 0;

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            sessionCount++;
        }

        System.out.println("Session Created: " + event.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + sessionCount);
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            sessionCount--;
        }
        System.out.println("Session Destroyed: " + event.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + sessionCount);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>SessionListener</display-name>
    <distributable/>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

My requirement is : When there is no interaction of user with the session for 1 minute, i want to invalidate session depending on some database value. If database value is false then session should not be invalidated. If database value is true then session should be invalidated. But after 1 minuter(when there is no interaction of user with the session), sessionDestroyed function of SessionListener class is automatically called and i am not able to check database value. How can i do this?

Comment: the database value you need to check might change during the lifetime of the session?

Comment: Thankx for reply! yes, This database value is continuouly updating by some other application,so it can be any value at any time true or false

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

- Add the sessions to the Custom Management Thread
- At reqular interval the Custom Management Thread should do the below steps.

  - Lets the Custom Management Thread read the DB Value
  - If the invalidate session is disabled in DB, let the management thread increase the session timeout value using `setMaxInactiveInterval`. The value `-1`  means `Never Invalidate.`
  - If the invalidate session is enabled in DB, let the management thread reduce the session timeout value by setting smaller value in `setMaxInactiveInterval`.

Comment: Can u please direct me to some piece of code or can u give me your code or working example illustrating custom management thread(not database retrieval)

Comment: Hmm, give me some time, i will try to give you something.